# При клике на кнопку остановить поиск формы

Tags: javascript

Есть форма. При клике `submit` появляется прелоадер с кнопкой `Stop`. Нужно при клике на кнопку `Stop` остановить или удалить event submit. C `.off()` почему то не работает, поиск все равно отрабатывает.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var form = document.getElementById("form");
  var preloader = document.getElementById("preloader");
    
  form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    Preloader();
    setTimeout(function() {
     preloader.style.display = "none";
    }, 7000);
  })
  
  function Preloader() {
    preloader.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```css
#preloader {
  width:100%;
 height:100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: beige;
  display:none;
}
#fountainG{
 position:absolute;
 width:210px;
 height:25px;
 top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#stop-btn {
  position:absolute;
 top: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.fountainG{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 width:25px;
 height:25px;
 animation-name:bounce_fountainG;
  -o-animation-name:bounce_fountainG;
  -ms-animation-name:bounce_fountainG;
  -webkit-animation-name:bounce_fountainG;
  -moz-animation-name:bounce_fountainG;
 animation-duration:1.5s;
  -o-animation-duration:1.5s;
  -ms-animation-duration:1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-duration:1.5s;
  -moz-animation-duration:1.5s;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 animation-direction:normal;
  -o-animation-direction:normal;
  -ms-animation-direction:normal;
  -webkit-animation-direction:normal;
  -moz-animation-direction:normal;
 transform:scale(.3);
  -o-transform:scale(.3);
  -ms-transform:scale(.3);
  -webkit-transform:scale(.3);
  -moz-transform:scale(.3);
 border-radius:17px;
  -o-border-radius:17px;
  -ms-border-radius:17px;
  -webkit-border-radius:17px;
  -moz-border-radius:17px;
}

#fountainG_1{
 left:0;
 animation-delay:0.6s;
  -o-animation-delay:0.6s;
  -ms-animation-delay:0.6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:0.6s;
  -moz-animation-delay:0.6s;
}

#fountainG_2{
 left:26px;
 animation-delay:0.75s;
  -o-animation-delay:0.75s;
  -ms-animation-delay:0.75s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:0.75s;
  -moz-animation-delay:0.75s;
}

#fountainG_3{
 left:52px;
 animation-delay:0.9s;
  -o-animation-delay:0.9s;
  -ms-animation-delay:0.9s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:0.9s;
  -moz-animation-delay:0.9s;
}

#fountainG_4{
 left:79px;
 animation-delay:1.05s;
  -o-animation-delay:1.05s;
  -ms-animation-delay:1.05s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:1.05s;
  -moz-animation-delay:1.05s;
}

#fountainG_5{
 left:105px;
 animation-delay:1.2s;
  -o-animation-delay:1.2s;
  -ms-animation-delay:1.2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:1.2s;
  -moz-animation-delay:1.2s;
}

#fountainG_6{
 left:131px;
 animation-delay:1.35s;
  -o-animation-delay:1.35s;
  -ms-animation-delay:1.35s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:1.35s;
  -moz-animation-delay:1.35s;
}

#fountainG_7{
 left:157px;
 animation-delay:1.5s;
  -o-animation-delay:1.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay:1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:1.5s;
  -moz-animation-delay:1.5s;
}

#fountainG_8{
 left:184px;
 animation-delay:1.64s;
  -o-animation-delay:1.64s;
  -ms-animation-delay:1.64s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:1.64s;
  -moz-animation-delay:1.64s;
}



@keyframes bounce_fountainG{
 0%{
 transform:scale(1);
  background-color:rgb(102,53,102);
 }

 100%{
 transform:scale(.3);
  background-color:rgb(217,208,217);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes bounce_fountainG{
 0%{
 -o-transform:scale(1);
  background-color:rgb(102,53,102);
 }

 100%{
 -o-transform:scale(.3);
  background-color:rgb(217,208,217);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes bounce_fountainG{
 0%{
 -ms-transform:scale(1);
  background-color:rgb(102,53,102);
 }

 100%{
 -ms-transform:scale(.3);
  background-color:rgb(217,208,217);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce_fountainG{
 0%{
 -webkit-transform:scale(1);
  background-color:rgb(102,53,102);
 }

 100%{
 -webkit-transform:scale(.3);
  background-color:rgb(217,208,217);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce_fountainG{
 0%{
 -moz-transform:scale(1);
  background-color:rgb(102,53,102);
 }

 100%{
 -moz-transform:scale(.3);
  background-color:rgb(217,208,217);
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="preloader">
<button type="button" id="stop-btn">Stop</button>
  <div id="fountainG">
    <div id="fountainG_1" class="fountainG"></div>
    <div id="fountainG_2" class="fountainG"></div>
    <div id="fountainG_3" class="fountainG"></div>
    <div id="fountainG_4" class="fountainG"></div>
    <div id="fountainG_5" class="fountainG"></div>
    <div id="fountainG_6" class="fountainG"></div>
    <div id="fountainG_7" class="fountainG"></div>
    <div id="fountainG_8" class="fountainG"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">Найти</button>
</form>
```

Comment: да вроде нет, ничего не происходит

Answer (score 1):

1. Не мешайте код, если пишите на нативном, то и пишите всё на нативном.
2. Где подправил код выделил `///`.
3. Не забывайте ставить `;`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form = document.getElementById("form");
  var preloader = document.getElementById("preloader");

  /// Запишим ссылку на тайм аут
  let my_time;

  form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Preloader();
    my_time = setTimeout(function() {
      preloader.style.display = "none";
    }, 7000);
  });
  
  ///
  $('#stop-btn').on('click', function(){
    clearTimeout(my_time);
    StopPreloader();
  });

  function Preloader() {
    preloader.style.display = "block";
  }

  function StopPreloader() {
    preloader.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
#preloader {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: beige;
  display:none;
}
#fountainG{
  position:absolute;
  width:210px;
  height:25px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#stop-btn {
  position:absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.fountainG{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  animation-name:bounce_fountainG;
    -o-animation-name:bounce_fountainG;
    -ms-animation-name:bounce_fountainG;
    -webkit-animation-name:bounce_fountainG;
    -moz-animation-name:bounce_fountainG;
  animation-duration:1.5s;
    -o-animation-duration:1.5s;
    -ms-animation-duration:1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1.5s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-direction:normal;
    -o-animation-direction:normal;
    -ms-animation-direction:normal;
    -webkit-animation-direction:normal;
    -moz-animation-direction:normal;
  transform:scale(.3);
    -o-transform:scale(.3);
    -ms-transform:scale(.3);
    -webkit-transform:scale(.3);
    -moz-transform:scale(.3);
  border-radius:17px;
    -o-border-radius:17px;
    -ms-border-radius:17px;
    -webkit-border-radius:17px;
    -moz-border-radius:17px;
}

#fountainG_1{
  left:0;
  animation-delay:0.6s;
    -o-animation-delay:0.6s;
    -ms-animation-delay:0.6s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.6s;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.6s;
}

#fountainG_2{
  left:26px;
  animation-delay:0.75s;
    -o-animation-delay:0.75s;
    -ms-animation-delay:0.75s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.75s;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.75s;
}

#fountainG_3{
  left:52px;
  animation-delay:0.9s;
    -o-animation-delay:0.9s;
    -ms-animation-delay:0.9s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.9s;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.9s;
}

#fountainG_4{
  left:79px;
  animation-delay:1.05s;
    -o-animation-delay:1.05s;
    -ms-animation-delay:1.05s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1.05s;
    -moz-animation-delay:1.05s;
}

#fountainG_5{
  left:105px;
  animation-delay:1.2s;
    -o-animation-delay:1.2s;
    -ms-animation-delay:1.2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1.2s;
    -moz-animation-delay:1.2s;
}

#fountainG_6{
  left:131px;
  animation-delay:1.35s;
    -o-animation-delay:1.35s;
    -ms-animation-delay:1.35s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1.35s;
    -moz-animation-delay:1.35s;
}

#fountainG_7{
  left:157px;
  animation-delay:1.5s;
    -o-animation-delay:1.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay:1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay:1.5s;
}

#fountainG_8{
  left:184px;
  animation-delay:1.64s;
    -o-animation-delay:1.64s;
    -ms-animation-delay:1.64s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1.64s;
    -moz-animation-delay:1.64s;
}



@keyframes bounce_fountainG{
  0%{
  transform:scale(1);
    background-color:rgb(102,53,102);
  }

  100%{
  transform:scale(.3);
    background-color:rgb(217,208,217);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes bounce_fountainG{
  0%{
  -o-transform:scale(1);
    background-color:rgb(102,53,102);
  }

  100%{
  -o-transform:scale(.3);
    background-color:rgb(217,208,217);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes bounce_fountainG{
  0%{
  -ms-transform:scale(1);
    background-color:rgb(102,53,102);
  }

  100%{
  -ms-transform:scale(.3);
    background-color:rgb(217,208,217);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce_fountainG{
  0%{
  -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    background-color:rgb(102,53,102);
  }

  100%{
  -webkit-transform:scale(.3);
    background-color:rgb(217,208,217);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce_fountainG{
  0%{
  -moz-transform:scale(1);
    background-color:rgb(102,53,102);
  }

  100%{
  -moz-transform:scale(.3);
    background-color:rgb(217,208,217);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="preloader">
<button type="button" id="stop-btn">Stop</button>
  <div id="fountainG">
    <div id="fountainG_1" class="fountainG"></div>
    <div id="fountainG_2" class="fountainG"></div>
    <div id="fountainG_3" class="fountainG"></div>
    <div id="fountainG_4" class="fountainG"></div>
    <div id="fountainG_5" class="fountainG"></div>
    <div id="fountainG_6" class="fountainG"></div>
    <div id="fountainG_7" class="fountainG"></div>
    <div id="fountainG_8" class="fountainG"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">Найти</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Это мы скрываем прелоадер, а мне нужно остановить поиск.

Comment: @Mr.V, а где у вас процесс поиска?